# Fading out in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey I'm new to javascript and I'm working on a small chat program right now.

I've got all the chatlogs (global& private and stuff..) but i want to add a button which can make (most of) the elements of these little 'clients' fade out and in, so that you dont have to see ALL of them at one time, just the ones you want.

The (relevant) code with the example element `mess1`:

```
 h=0;
    newroom = function (roomname) {
        //create new container
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'container';
        //new text input
        var mess = document.createElement('input');
        mess.type = 'text';
        mess.id = 'mess1' + i;
        div.appendChild(mess);
        //minimizer button
        var min = document.createElement('input');
        min.type = 'button';
        min.value = 'Minimize chat';
        min.id = 'min' + i;
        div.appendChild(min);
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        document.getElementById("min" + h).addEventListener("click", function (){
        //this is where the magic happens
        }
        h++;
    };
```

I've tried `document.getElementById("mess1" + h).style.visibility = 'hidden';`, but that just makes the element disappear, leaving a big ugly blank space behind.

I thought `document.getElementById("mess1" + h).fadeOut('slow');` would fix that, but it just doesn't do anything...

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: You need to use jQuery like `$("#mess1" + h).fadeOut('slow')`

Comment: @jcubic $("#mess1" + h).fadeOut('slow')

Comment: It does do something. Look at the console, and you should see an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all I will recommend to use jQuery, it will make your life much more easy. In jQuery, you can fade the element and then remove it like this

```
 $("#mess1" + h).fadeOut('slow',function(){
     $("#mess1" + h).remove();
});
```

It will first fade the element and will then remove it from node if required

Comment: i actually thought about using jquery, but i wasnt sure how. Thanks for the enlightment :D

Comment: just import the jQuery file to page and then use it, within few days you will realize the difference :)

Comment: however you should consider using another framework for animations (e.g. http://greensock.com/ or http://julian.com/research/velocity/)

Comment: Please add reason for downvoting

Answer (score 1):

```
function fadeout(element) {
    var op = 1;  // initial opacity
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op <= 0.1){
            clearInterval(timer);
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op -= op * 0.1;
    }, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
document.getElementById("mess1" + h).style.display= 'none';
```

it will hide element without empty space. But if you whant to hide element with animation you can use eq. this jquery:

```
$("#mess1" + h).hide('slow')
```

or eq. 'fast' - as parameter